# SSIS project error. Cannot access Excel sheets

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ssis, business-intelligence

I'm trying to make simple `SSIS` project. After making all neseccary connections (one database and one Excel connection), in `Data Flow` tab I put `Excel source` and by right click press `edit.` There I can't reach my sheet names. Error is:

```
Could not retrieve the table information for the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'.
Failed to connect to the source using the connection manager 'Excel Connection Manager'
```

I surfed the Internet, and found that it is due to bit versions (mine is `64`). And I tried to do all instructions in the web to fix the problem, but all my efforts come to `MS Office is 64 bit, delete it and install 32 bit.` There should be some other ways. Could you please help.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, i remember this bug.
i fix the problem with this suggest
http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20run%20SSIS%20Packages%20using%2032bit%20drivers%20on%2064bit%20machine.htm

Comment: I've tried this, error is the same. I'm trying to do step 6 of this tutorial https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server---10-steps-to-follow/

Comment: ok try to donwload ed put the dll of 32bit in the ssis folder.

Comment: One more stupid question, what is dll and where exactly do I have to put it?

Comment: try with this, http://ssis-ssdt.blogspot.co.at/2013/01/how-to-fix-errors-microsoft.html

Comment: and with this http://sqljunkieshare.com/2014/02/17/unspecified-error-ssis-excel-connection-manager/